# Assign different coupons to different user groups in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using many of the code chunks I found mostly here, and I got stuck on this last part.

I would like to write a function that filters through current user:

```
   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

And then conclude if and which group is user the part of:

```
   $group = Groups_Group::read_by_name( 'group_name' );
```

And of course, write a conditional if the user is in group A, B, C, D, E

```
   if ( Groups_User_Group::read( $user_id, $group->group_id ) ) {
```

Than use coupon code 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

```
   $coupon_code = '1';
```

You probably see the problem forming right here, as I cannot figure out how to get this stuffed in one function. It works if I write separate functions, but I would really like to do it better, so that it goes something like:

```
   if user is in group A, use coupon_1, if user is in group B, use coupon:2...
```

How would it be possible to get current group without having to state it in read_by_name?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a plugin that actually work in a way I wanted to, I just tried a demo and it seems like a solution so I am gonna pull the trigger and buy it. If it turns out a solution in practice, will post here for others in similar position to know. Thanks all!